# How to digitally sign a DB record and verify later on if it is signed

Tags: sql-server, digital-signature

Is it possible to achieve these functionalities using SQL Server?

- Digitally sign database records using a connected application user's signature.
- Check later on if a certain record is signed or not.
- Know the username of the application user who signed a certain record; something like `select username from users where signature='signature_used_to_sign_record'`.

thanks in advance.

Comment: this may help you:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20630115/digitally-signing-an-sql-server-database-record-or-an-insert-update-operation

Comment: @TheGameiswar Thank you, it helps when it comes to signing the record, but can't say the same about checking if a record is signed or not