# Can a database record in MySQl be digitally signed?

Tags: mysql, digital-signature

How to digitally sign a database record in MySQl, like we sign the pdf and other documents ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Digitally signing an SQL Server database record or an insert/update operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20630115/digitally-signing-an-sql-server-database-record-or-an-insert-update-operation)

Comment: @Maritim that applies to ms sql server only, not to MySQL, therefore it is not a duplicate.

Comment: You cannot sign a record, you can sign some kind of a representation of the contents of all fields in a record.

Comment: The general principles mentioned in @Maritim's link explain how to apply a signature (or any verification hash) to the columns in a row of a database. It's going to take some programming to do this in MySQL.

Comment: @O.Jones a lot of programming, since MySQL in itself does not have any functionality to sign data. You would have to implement it as a compiled UDF.